# Get the content from iframe of external url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe, cross-domain

I need to get the content(Complete html) of a page (say.: someotherdomain.com/somepage) loaded in iframe from an asp.net mvc (C#) application without using webclient or httpwebrequest.

Answer (score 0):

That's simply not possible. Your browser blocks the javascript in external sites (when in frame), just like with Ajax requests.